# How can I install all .net versions on a new Azure VM

Tags: .net, azure, windows-server-2003, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I created a new windows server 2016 datacenter IaaS VM that I need to get a web server that is old and on-premises and migrate all the IIS websites to Azure.

Now I ran a few tools on local server 2003 machine.

```
 Raymondcc .net detector

 Asoft .net version detector
```

Both end up confirming that this server has

```
.NET 1.1 Service Pack 1
.NET 2.0 Service Pack 2
.NET 3.0 Service Pack 2
.NET 3.5 Service Pack 1
.NET 4.0 Client Package
.NET 4.0 Full Package
```

So regardless really if it is on Azure or not,  I have RDP to to and full install access.  Until I have time to re-write hundreds of apps,  I believe that I would need to install all of these versions of .net?

How can and should I go about this for installing them?

Download the framework or the SDK?

Comment: That is so helpful, I never thought of that

Comment: @JeremyMiller - I think 4c's point is that Azure isn't a factor here. Whether you do this via RDP / manually, or utilize some type of PowerShell script, there's no diff between on-premises and in-Azure installation (assuming it's the same Windows Server version).

Comment: Notice my original question states "So regardless really if it is on Azure or not"   Thus i know that, but adding the fact that I want to does mass migrations instead of installation 1 thing at a time,  if 4c does not know any special packages or github powershell scripts etc.. then maybe he just should not comment.

Comment: The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2 *Why* do you want to install earlier versions? How is this related to programming anyway? Do you have an actual application that requires an unsupported version?

Comment: BTW the earliest supported Windows Server is 2012. Looks like you already have to either rewrite a lot of applications or simply change the target runtime version in each application's `app.config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  so use this software

```
Asoft .net version detector
```

Double check that you really have and need 1.1 ( circa 2003 Visual Studio 2003  )   ,  I doubt it, ...  but you can use powershell etc..

2.0 -3.5

```
 Click on the net 2.0 download ,  you will see it but notice that 2012 won't let you install it..

 Roles go into that, and then IIS,  find 3.5 ,  get your ISO mounted if a VM, or have CD/DVD of win 2012 and then you point at  D:\sources\xsx
```

3.5 runs the 2.0 , so after 3.5 install , you will have  2.0-3.5

4.0 you do NOT need,  4.5/4.6  already is going to cover the 4.0 stuff